# No puedo acceder al return de una función pero si lo imprime en consola

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo este controlador de imagenes que me retorna un objeto con un error y/o una cadena en base64 de una foto que he subido

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageHandlerService {

  constructor() { }

  handler( file: any,  inSize?: number, inWidth?: number, inHeight?: number ): any {
    const obj: any = { file: null, error: null };
    if ( !file ) {
      obj['file']  = null;
      obj['error'] = 'No se recibió la imagen';
      return obj;
    }

    const imageType = /image.*/;
    if ( !file.type.match( imageType) ) {
      obj['file']  = null;
      obj['error'] = 'El archivo recibido no es una imagen';
      return obj;
    }

    if ( inSize ) {
      const KBIn   = Math.ceil( inSize );
      const KBFile = Math.ceil( file.size / 1024 );
      console.log( KBFile, KBIn );
      if ( KBIn < KBFile ) {
        obj['file']  = null;
        obj['error'] = `Peso de fichero excedido. Permitido ${ KBIn }KB, enviado ${ KBFile }KB.`;
        return obj;
      }
    }

    const reader: any = new FileReader();
    const img: any    = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL( file );

    const imgPromise = new Promise( (resolve: any) => {
      img.onload = () => {
          resolve( { width: img.width, height: img.height } );
      };
    });

    const onloadPromise = new Promise( (resolve: any) => {
      reader.onload = () => {
        if ( inHeight && inWidth ) {

          img.src = reader.result;
          imgPromise.then( (res: any) => {
            if ( res.width > inWidth || res.height > inHeight ) {
              const ret = {
                file: null,
                error: `Archivo sobredimensionado. Actual: ${ res.width }x${res.height}. Permitido: ${inWidth}x${inHeight}`
              };
              resolve( ret );
            } else {
              resolve({file: reader.result, error: null});
            }
          });

        } else {
          resolve({file: reader.result, error: null});
        }
      };
    });

    onloadPromise.then( (res: any) => {
      obj['file'] = res.file;
      obj['error'] = res.error;
    });
    return obj;
  }
}
```

El controlador funciona perfecto, hace lo que tiene que hacer, y regresa a la función con la que se invocó

```
  changePhoto( photo: any ) {
    const uploaded = this.ihandler.handler( photo.files[0] );
    console.log( uploaded );
  }
```

No hay problemas en la parte de la inyección del `ihandler` en el constructor, digo, todo lo hace muy bien, pero cuando veo en consola la respuesta aparece `{ file:null, error:null }` pero si despliego el objeto, viene con la información.

**Así viene con el console.log**
[image: Esta null]

**Y así está si lo despliego**
[image: Ya no está null]

Si hago `console.log( uploaded.file, uploaded.error )` sale `undefined undefined` Como si no estuviera trayendo nada, pero en realidad si se procesó.

Es un issue del navegador? Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no es un issue el navegador, se debe a que en tu **servicio** estás retornando el objeto `obj` antes de que le sean asignados los valores, sin embargo puedes ver el pequeño ícono azul de `info` que indica que los valores han cambido.

Lo que necesitas hacer en tu Service, es retornar únicamente la promesa, y en tu componente esperar por medio del método `then` a que esa promesa se resuelva

**Service**:

```
// Haces las demás funciones que tengas que hacer ... 

return onloadPromise = new Promise( (resolve: any) => {
      reader.onload = () => {
        if ( inHeight && inWidth ) {

          img.src = reader.result;
          imgPromise.then( (res: any) => {
            if ( res.width > inWidth || res.height > inHeight ) {
              const ret = {
                file: null,
                error: `Archivo sobredimensionado. Actual: ${ res.width }x${res.height}. Permitido: ${inWidth}x${inHeight}`
              };
              resolve( ret );
            } else {
              resolve({file: reader.result, error: null});
            }
          });

        } else {
          resolve({file: reader.result, error: null});
        }
      };
    });
```

Y en tu componente donde lo implementes:

```
 changePhoto( photo: any ) {
    const uploaded = this.ihandler.handler( photo.files[0] ).then(res => {
         console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes básicamente es esto:

```js
const promesa = () => {

  const obj = {
    prop1: "",
    prop2: ""
  };

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => { // <-- Una modificación asíncrona
      obj.prop1 = "val1";
      obj.prop2 = "val2";
      resolve(obj);
    }, 1000);

  });
  
  return obj; // <-- En realidad estamos retornando el objeto vacío


}

console.log(promesa());
```

Si lanzas ese código en la consola del navegador, verás que sucede lo mismo que a tu código. Junto al objeto, hay una **i** si te posas sobre esa **i** dice algo como  **el valor se esta evaluando justo ahora**. Lo que sucede es que el objeto no está "*lleno*" al momento de hacer el console, pero si al momento de mirarlo.

Para solucionarlo, deberías usar await async o retornar la promesa y hacer then(), algo como:

```js
const promesa = () => {

  const obj = {
    prop1: "",
    prop2: ""
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <-- retornamos la promesa

    setTimeout(() => {
      obj.prop1 = "val1";
      obj.prop2 = "val2";
      resolve(obj);
    }, 1000);

  });


}

promesa().then((res)=>console.log(res));
```

Para usar el await, que se hace desde una función async, deberías hacer algo como:

```
(async()=>console.log(await promesa()))();
```

en la última línea.

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizar un setTimeout dentro de una promesa?

Comment: @A.Medina Porque es la forma de representar algo asíncrono en la consola, sin necesidad de hacer un ajax o algo así.

Comment: `async changePhoto() { const uploaded = await this.ihandler.handler() }` Lo hice así pero sigue igual, no entiendo donde va el `async` y el `await`

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Eso entiendo que está bien, pero para que funcione, debes retornar la promesa y no el objeto.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob perdón el async debería estar en la definición de la funcion osea que debería ser algo como `async function changePhoto() { const uploaded = await this.ihandler.handler() }` y cuidado que no estas haciendo ni return ni console